# Find Element with wait confusion Selenium c#

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my learning curve I have been looking at the right way to wait for an element to be loaded and you get lots of pages on google.

Got down to 2 but in my view Method2(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible) is more elegant and does what method1 is trying to achieve do you agree or is there a better way?

Method 1

```
        public static IWebElement FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
        {
            if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
            {
                var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
                return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
            }
            return driver.FindElement(by);
        }
```

Method 2

```
  public static IWebElement FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
            var element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by));
            return element;
        }
```

Any suggestions or improvements also what happens if "NoFoundElement exception is thrown is it already handled or should I ignore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say **yes**, "Method 2" is the preferred way of doing it. Simply because if something is already implemented in WebDriver, there's no need for you to reimplement it in your testing framework.

As to your question regarding the `NotFoundException`: If the condition that you're waiting for isn't met after the specified timeout, the `WebDriverWait` will raise a `WebDriverTimeoutException`. Depending on the condition that you wanted to wait for, the `WebDriverTimeoutException` will have an inner exception with more details. If for example you use `ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("myid"))` and the element couldn't be located at all, the inner exception will be a `NoSuchElementException`. If the element could be located but isn't visible after the given timeout you'll just get the `WebDriverTimeoutException`.

Depending on what you want to do once you're sure that the element is "there", you can also use different `ExpectedConditions`. If the element you're waiting for is a button and you want to click on it, you can use `ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable` as this will not only wait for the element to get loaded into the DOM and visible, but also wait for the element to get enabled.

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I thought was the case.Do you happen to know  the difference between DefaultWait vs WebdriverWait? I m confused

Comment: `DefaultWait` is the base class of `WebDriverWait`. Note that `DefaultWait` is a generic implementation (e.g., it has a type parameter `T`), `WebDriverWait` is a sub class of DefaultWait where `T` becomes `IWebDriver`. The idea of `DefaultWait` is that it allows you to have a standardized way of "waiting for stuff, with the help of a `T` object to determine whether the event you're waiting for has already happened". `WebDriverWait` uses that functionality in a way that it uses an `IWebDriver` object to determine whether the event has occurred.